# Framework not found FirebaseCoreDiagnostics : Flutter 3.2.8 version

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

Unable to build and run flutter project after this error....

The error message you are encountering in Xcode indicates that there is an issue with the FirebaseCoreDiagnostics framework and that the linker command failed. This can happen due to various reasons, but let's go through some common troubleshooting steps to resolve this issue:

** ERROR **

````
Building com.example.name for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 763X932N22
Running pod install...                                           1,963ms
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           22.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Framework not found FirebaseCoreDiagnostics

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Encountered error while building for device.```
````